# Does UIAlertController's dismiss method without animation execute synchronously?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

If I call (In an `UIViewController`)

```
alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
print("executed after dismiss?")
```

Given that alert is a previously presented `UIAlertController`, does the dismiss method execute synchronously?

Could I do:

```
alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
let newAlert = UIAlertController(...)
present(newAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Without having to worry about a problem while presenting `newAlert`?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I've try it and it works, but I don't now if it is really synchronous, or good luck. I don't know if I could be sure that it will always work

Comment: Why don't you just present `newAlert` from inside the dismiss completion handler? Given that `dismiss(...)` takes a callback as an argument It leads me to believe that it is an asynchronous method although I am not positive, but to be safe you can just present the new alert from the completion block

Comment: I've tried that, but when `alert` has already been dismissed (if the user taps on the action, for example), the dismiss completion callback is not being called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like most animation methods when you dismiss the `UIAlertController` you are just getting the ball rolling. The view controller is dismissed and removed asynchronously. To test this we can use some code like this:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oh No!", message: ":(", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
print(presentedViewController) // Optional(<UIAlertController: 0x7fefe901e670>)

alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
print(presentedViewController) // Optional(<UIAlertController: 0x7fefe901e670>)
```

As demonstrated above the alert view controller is not removed as the presented view controller right away. You can still present the new alert right after dismissing the old alert. However best practice would be to place your code for the second alert in the completion handler of the first. This completion handler is called after `viewDidDisappear` is called on the presented view controller.

Comment: If I call `alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion:nil)` the situation is the same? It remains asynchronously?

Comment: Yes regardless of whether it's animated it will run asynchronously.

Comment: If this answers your question please accept the answer. Thanks!